# How to prerender without doing the whole rebuild again?

Tags: svelte, server-side-rendering, vite, sveltekit

My sveltekit app is connected to a DB. Ideally, I'd like to be able to only run the prerendering process. Because my build takes like 6 minutes because of a huge package "monaco-editor". And I have to regenerate pre-rendered files very often following updates to the db.

I'll be really thankful for any hints in the right direction.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is stopping you from using "vite dev" to generate one page at the time?

Comment: `vite dev` is for development. I'm interested in the production build.

Comment: It's called `Incremental Static Regeneration`. Next.js is already introduced. In case of SvelteKit, it's on the table, but for now I think you won't achieve that functionality.

Comment: Thanks @gyurielf I checked the related issues on sveltekit github, they don't seem very convinced of this feature.